# Sitecore User Group Aug 2019 Meetup - Queen City, Manchester, NH

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

We are super thrilled to announce the Aug'19 meetup of the Queen City Sitecore User Group!

Two excellent presentation are lined up for this SUG:

My Sitecore MVP journey by Peter Procházka - Sitecore Technology MVP 2019, Sitecore Solutions Architect at Accenture

Getting Started With Behavioral Based Personalization by Ed Kapuscinski - Senior Architect at TA Digital and a five time Sitecore MVP

Date & Time (EST):- Wednesday, Aug, 14, 2019 6:00 PM

Date & Time (UTC):- Wednesday, Aug, 14, 2019 10:00 PM

Venue:- SilverTech Inc, 196 Bridge Street, Manchester, NH 03104

[Click here](https://www.meetup.com/Queen-City-Sitecore-User-Group/events/263438156/) for more details and RSVP.

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion began Aug 4 at 22:00